# How are difficulties different?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

There are 3 difficulties to choose from.  What are the differences between them?  Are some things only unlock-able on harder difficulties or can you unlock everything on easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Monsters have more health. They also appear to be more intelligent and aggressive on hero mode. They also do a boatload more damage (lizalfos hit for something in the ballpark of 7 hearts on hero mode, not sure about hard or easy).
- Once you beat the game, you'll see that there are skulltulas that are only available on hard, for example.
- Reward-wise, higher difficulties provide more rupees on a victory, as well as better items.

I have no observations on friendly troops yet.

Comment: Alright, but what exactly makes hard different than normal? Do enemies just have more health? Do they attack harder? Are their fighting patterns different? What about friendly troops?

Comment: @Batophobia updated. Not sure about friendly troops but the rest is there.